# Android flavors with different dependencies and same class file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-proguard

I have two different flavors of my Android app, **lite** and **pro**. In the app, I have a class called *customFragment.java* that is included in main (not different between flavors) and including also following code:

```
import haibison.android.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity;    

private void showLockPattern() {
    if (BuildConfig.IS_VERSION_PRO) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA, null, this, LockPatternActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PATTERN_ID);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PATTERN_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.i("App", "OK!");
    }
}
```

And in app.gradle I have included the LockPattern library only for the pro flavor:

```
dependencies {
    proCompile 'com.github.haibison:android-lockpattern:6.0.0'
}
```

The class that I described in the same for both flavors (so in main folder) since it's quite big and I don't want to duplicate the code in both flavors. The **pro** flavor builds successfully but the **lite** flavor shows an error since I don't import the dependency for the **lite** flavor as well.

One solution that I see would be to add the lockpattern library to both flavors but then using proGuard removing it from the **lite** flavor. Although I believe this might work, it's probably not the smoothest option. Of course I could also simply ignore the overhead of unused library in the **lite** flavor.

How would you tackle this problem? I've searched across stackoverflow for long time but have not found any answer, so for the first time in few years I had decided to register and ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lite version is not compiling because java cannot find LockPatternActivity. For that thing you can use following solution.

You need to have a class in flavor **pro**

```
public final class LockPatternHelper {
    private LockPatternHelper() {}

    public static void showLockPattern() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_VERIFY_CAPTCHA, null, this, LockPatternActivity.class);
         startActivityForResult(intent, PATTERN_ID);
    }
}
```

In flavor **lite** it should be same class with empty method *showLockPattern()*.

```
public final class LockPatternHelper {
    private LockPatternHelper() {}

    public static void showLockPattern() {}
}
```

After this you can call *LockPatternHelper.showLockPattern()* from your *customFragment.java*

Every flavor will use it's helper and **lite** version will not contain unnecessary library.